# Toggle boolean value using hooks in React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Taking my first pass using hooks and running into some issues toggling a boolean value. I can toggle the style when clicking "complete" on an individual item but when I click another "complete" on another item it doesn't fire until you click for the second time.

Below is sandbox URL to help explain what I am running into.

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-to-do-with-hooks-mpqfl

Comment: It seems to strike through the appropriate line every time I hit complete. What exactly isn't working for you?

Comment: Click one then click another. Check out the console log. "
Object {text: "Learn about React", isCompleted: true}
Object {text: "Meet friend for lunch", isCompleted: false}"

Comment: text: "Meet friend for lunch", isCompleted: false":  isCompleted should be true

Comment: @user992731 Please, make sure you provided correct codesandbox url. I don't see any output in console

Comment: @phen0menon - Sorry about that. Updated the URL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need `status` to achieve what you are trying to do here.

Here is an updated sandbox which works as expected https://codesandbox.io/s/react-to-do-with-hooks-tvyg2

Your sandbox doesn't work as you are using only 1 variable `status` to control all your To-Do items.

To explain it better, say there are 2 To-Dos:
1.Learn react
2.Meet friend for lunch
 
The default value of `status` is `false` at first then you mark the first to do as completed and set the value of `status` as `true`.
<strike>1.Learn react</strike>
2.Meet friend for lunch
 
Everything works as expected as of now.
Now the value of `status` is `true`

When you try to mark the 2nd to do as completed with the code here:

```
 newTodos[index].isCompleted = !status;
```

`isCompleted` is again assigned `false` i.e. not completed as `!status` is `false` at this point. So no changes occur in your To-Do list.

Following this line you again set `status` as `false` here.

```
setStatus(!status);
```

Now the new value of `status` is `false`.
So when you click on the same To-Do the 2nd time, `isCompleted` is set to `!status` i.e `true` and the list changes to:
 
<strike>1.Learn react</strike>
<strike>2.Meet friend for lunch</strike>

As you were using only 1 variable to track the status of all To-Dos you were facing the observed behaviour
i.e you had to click the button twice to mark it as complete

Comment: Glad, I was able to help!